# smarttable (ui.table) not requesting all data

Tags: sapui5

my smarttable already shows Service data.
We have to use the grid table (ui.table) for desktop.

```
<smartTable:SmartTable id="ReportSmartTable" entitySet="DocumentSet" tableBindingPath="/DocumentSet" tableType="Table" header="Document" showRowCount="true" enableAutoBinding="true" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding" showFullScreenButton="true" smartFilterId="smartFilterBar" useVariantManagement="false" persistencyKey="SmartTableUEreport" useTablePersonalisation="true">

    <ui:Table id="table" busyIndicatorDelay="{worklistView>/tableBusyDelay}" selectionMode="MultiToggle" visibleRowCount="10" visibleRowCountMode="Auto" fixedColumnCount="1" rowActionCount="1" class="sapUiSizeCompact sapUiSizeCondensed"></ui:Table>
</smartTable:SmartTable>
```

## Problem

In the batch request, I see that only a part of the data is loaded. skip and top are automatically added.
Since I am using the UI.table I can not use the growing functionality of the m.table.

How do I request the rest of the data by using the smarttable (ui.table)?

Comment: I believe further records will be loaded as you scroll down.

Comment: Isn't SmartTable lazy by default?

Comment: I am just curious why I never see a second Batch request for the rest of the data